# Google Directory API Python ETL

Tags: python, google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to build a directory sync ETL for Google Workspace, but I'm getting 403's from the code snippet.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = './credentials.json' #TODO: these creds need to be passed in more safely.

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=credentials)

results = service.users().list(domain='mydomain.com').execute()
users = results.get('users', [])
```

The service account has been given domain-wide delegation to the listed scope and should be able to access the API. Other similar posts have mentioned that a domain administrator must approve the request, but that doesn't make sense in the case where I need this to run multiple times a week without any administrator intervention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Users API requires the *User Management Admin* role (or an equivalent custom role). You can [grant this role to a service account](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9807615?hl=en), then you won't need domain-wide delegation at all.